# Using ES6 Generators with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, ecmascript-6, generator

I'm trying to simplify how I make AJAX calls with ES6 generators. However, I'm running into some issues:

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

function *statechange() {
    yield xhr.readyState;
}

let gen = statechange();

xhr.open("GET", myUrl, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {console.log(gen.next())};
xhr.send();
```

Just a brief explanation of what I'm trying to do: I want to yield the ready-state of each request state change. I log the `readyState` string on each iteration of the generator. But when I run this code I get:

```
{value: 2, done: false}
{value: undefined, done: true}
{value: undefined, done: true}
```

Which, on its surface looks right, but if I do an old-fashioned XHR:

```
//... new XMLHttpRequest()...
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {console.log(xhr.readyState)}
```

I get:

```
2
3
4
```

So... where am I going wrong with my use of generators?

---

**UPDATE:**

Even stranger, if I log the `readyState` in the generator:

```
//                                                     HERE
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {console.log(xhr.readyState, gen.next())};
```

I get this:

```
2, {value: 2, done: false}
3, {value: undefined, done: true}
4, {value: undefined, done: true}
```

So this means, the correct `readyState` is available when the `next()` method is called. I can only guess that the `yield` statement I used only registers once, so the generator only allocates one slot. I figured that since `onreadystatechange` is called more than once, more slots would be allocated. How do I fix this?

Comment: `gen` reaches the end of the function and therefore is _done_ (also, this doesn't really simplify XHRs, instead listen for load/error and you can write them as promises)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you "call" a generator function, it runs until the first `yield` statement and then pauses until it's `next` method is called.  After this, it continues running until another `yield` statement occurs or the function or *control leaves the function*.  In the latter case, all calls to the `next` method will return `undefined`.

What you want is a loop that checks the `readyState` of the xhr on each iteration:

```
function *statechange() {
  while(true) { // loop forever
    yield xhr.readyState;
  }
}
```

If you're familiar with generators in Python, this is exactly the same.

I'm going to second @Paul S.'s comment that this doesn't really simplify xhrs, and you should check out promises for that.